# Can I hide a repeating string of HTML via javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom, hide

I don't know how to do this but I need to hide a repeating (50 times in one page) string of html from being displayed in the browser.

The offending line of html is something like:

```
<li><a href="actor" class="extLink">Empty</a></li>
```

I know this would be a hack but I can't alter the source of this list content.

Is there some javascript code I could put in the head of my document which could hide this string?

Many thanks,
Dar.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but if you just want to hide it from being displayed by the browser, how about using CSS? Just set it to `display:none`.

Comment: Do these links always have a literal text `Empty`. Also, is there any other links with the same class name, which should be preserved? How about the `li`, should we hide that too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use :contains to get elements based on their content.

HTML :

```
<li><a href="actor" class="extLink">Empty</a></li>
```

jQuery :

```
$('a:contains("Empty")').css('display', 'none');
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/9z5du/285

Comment: what if someone named Emptyton came up

Comment: But you can use each method.

Comment: @d.danailov  Where should I add this line? (I already have jquery running at the top of my document). Thanks.

Comment: see the top answer, he has a js solution

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});

More info : http://api.jquery.com/ready

Comment: @d.danailov Thanks again for your reply. I hate to ask you to literally spell this out for me but when I copy the example from the jquery page I get an error:

Comment: `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
  $("<li><a href="actor" class="extLink">Empty</a></li>").text("");
});
  </script> `

Comment: I need more info.

jQuery is added ?

Comment: @d.danailov That looks great. I can see now how that works. It's only just become clear to me though that the thing I need to hide is the whole list item IF the `href="actor"`   Can I please ask you to show how that might be done?

Comment: @d.danailov Yes, just to clarify, my output text is the same for all list items. It's only the href that varies. And I'd like to hide all the list items that have `actor` in their href.

Comment: Woo hoo I figured it out. I just had to modify @d.danailov jfiddle to 
`<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () 
{ 
    $('a[href*="actor"]').text(""); 
});
  </script>`

Answer (score 1):

You could hide them without any scripting by setting;

```
.extLink {
    display: none;
}
```

This will work whether or not JavaScript is enabled and it will mean they won't display even for a flash while the document loads.

If it is specifically the `actor` links, you can target those too - or if it is both you can make the rule cover both. Let me know if your requirement is more specific.

```
a[href=actor] {
    display: none;
}
```

If you want to hide them based on the content, you will need to use JavaScript.

```
var clearEmptyActorLinks = function () {
    var externalLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('extLink');
    for (var i = 0; i < externalLinks.length; i++) {
        if (externalLinks[i].innerHTML === 'Empty') {
            externalLinks[i].parentNode.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
};
window.onload = clearEmptyActorLinks;
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZnK59/

Comment: I think he only wants to hide the empty ones

Comment: Ah - that *would* require some JavaScript - example added.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I do only want to hide the empty ones, thanks anyway Steve.

Comment: I added an example for removing just those - and a link to a JS Fiddle of the script working.

Comment: @SteveFenton Sorry Steve I just saw your jsfiddle post. I got stuck into a back & forth with another poster above. I got it fixed using jquery (as that was already on the page). I really appreciate you taking the time though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
window.onload = function () {
    var n, hiddens = document.getElementsByClassName('extLink');
    for (n = 0; n < hiddens.length; n++) {
        if (hiddens[n].innerHTML === 'Empty')
            hiddens[n].style.display = 'none';
        }
        if (hiddens[n].href === 'actor') {
            hiddens[n].parentElement.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think he only wants to hide the "empty" ones

Comment: @Huangism You might be right, let's wait OP's response, I'll fix the code if needed. We can also hide `li`s of these links, if necessary.

Comment: Holy cow. Thanks for all the quick responses.

The only complicating factor is that sometimes on my page, I will have content within these list items that should be retained and are shown in the browser.

I can use query if needs be.

Answer (score -1):

Based on jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    var i = 0;
    $('li').each(function() {
       if (i == 0) {continue;i++}
       $(this).remove();
       i++;
    });
});
```

I'm not sure what are you looking for.
Removing empty tags:

```
$(function() {
    var i = 0;
    $('li').each(function() {
       if (i == 0) {continue;i++}
       var $obj = $(this);
       if ($obj.find('a').text() == 'Empty') {
          $obj.remove();
       }
       i++;
    });
});
```

Comment: OP does not mention jquery

Comment: ...and also does not mention that jQuery is prohibited.

Comment: he would of tagged it jquery if he can use it, also text() == 'Empty'

Comment: @Huangism & OP Thanks both for your input. I got it sorted above. I just didn't explain it fully first time around. I had to just pick one method and try it ... and it worked. So I'm happy. Yah Internet!